# How to make Angular Directive templates wrap content (child elements of the directive element)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've googled a bit and I can't find anything that details how to make Angular directives that wrap content dynamically (for example http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/panelbar/angular). I'm not very familiar with transclusion, but my understanding is it has more to do with how the Angular scopes fit together than how the HTML fits together.

Is the best way to just do a lot of DOM manipulation during the compile step? Or is there some way to use template functions to accomplish it?

EDIT: To give an example, I want this:

```
<directive>
    <div id="firstChild"></div>
    <div id="secondChild"></div>
</directive>
```

to compile to:

```
<directive>
    <div id="firstTemplateElement">
        <div id="firstChild"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="secondTemplateElement>
        <div id="secondChild"></div>
    </div>
</directive>
```

Comment: I'm confused what you are asking. Can you take a screenshot of what is happening and explain what you want to happen?

Comment: I edited my question to include an example.

Answer (score 1):

You could do alot of dom manipulation, but what it seems you are trying to do is provide a new template for each item inside the directive.  No reason you can't make each item a directive too.

```
<directive>
    <directive-item id="firstChild"></directive-item>
    <directive-item id="secondChild"></directive-item>
</directive>
```

compiles to:

```
<directive>
    <directive-item id="firstTemplateElement">
        <div id="firstChild"></div>
    </directive-item>
    <directive-item id="secondTemplateElement>
        <div id="secondChild"></div>
    </directive-item>
</directive>
```

Comment: I would like to do that but I cant figure out how to wrap the contents of a directive (directive-item). could you please explain how to do that?